# Exactly $q=p^n$ distinct roots in proof of Existence of Finite Fields

Tags: solution-verification, field-theory, finite-fields

This proof is pulled from Lidl's 'Finite Fields.' I'm trying to give a little more justification to the part I underlined.

[image]

I understand that $f(x)=x^q-x$ has at most deg$(f(x))=q$ roots over any field. I also understand that because $f(x)$ and $f'(x)=qx^{q-1}-1=-1$ share no common polynomial factor with positive degree, we know that $f(x)$ has no 'multiple zeros.' But why does this mean $F$, the splitting field in the above proof, contains exactly $q$ roots? Is the following reasoning sound?

"Let $a_1,a_2,...,a_q\in F$ be (possibly not all distinct) roots of $f(x)$. Note we use the upper bound of $q$-many roots since deg$(f(x))=q$. Now since $f(x)$ and $f'(x)$ share no common factor of pos. degree, we have that $a_1,a_2,...,a_q$ must all be distinct."

If the reasoning really is that trivial and I'm making a mountain of a molehole, I apologize. Thanks for any help.

Comment: What do you think the splitting field is? The splitting field is the field where the polynomial splits into linear factors. There must be $q$ linear factors, and there are no repeated factors.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: Hi Thomas. The way splitting field was introduced to me (in a different book than Lidl's, mind you), it is the smallest field extension containing some finite number of roots of f(x), for f(x) s.t. deg(f(x))>0. This vague definition is what I see in most books. If a splitting field always contains deg(f(x))-many roots, it seems that would be a more useful definition. Now I'm confused as to why this is not simply the def. of a splitting field.

Comment: “Some number of roots” is not the definition. The splitting field of $x^3-2$ over $\mathbb Q$ is not $F=\mathbb Q[\sqrt[3]2],$ because the polynomial doesn’t split to linear factors in $F.$ I suggest you read the definitions more carefully. There should be no book that defines splitting field this way.

Comment: No, for polynomials that are not separable, there is no field extension containing as many roots as the degree of the polynomial. That is the point of the notion of "multiple zeros". The splitting field of a polynomial is a field extension containing *all* roots of the polynomial. That should be the definition. Now, for a separable polynomial, that means it contains exactly as many roots as the polynomials degree.

Comment: Indeed, there can be multiple field extensions with *some* roots for a polynomial. But that would contradict the name “the splitting field,” under your reading of the definition, because there wouldn’t be one splitting field, but multiple. (I elided a condition that makes the splitting field unique - that the splitting field is the smallest field such that the polynomial factors to linear factors.)

Comment: See, for example, Wikipedia: “In abstract algebra, a splitting field of a polynomial with coefficients in a field is the smallest field extension of that field over which the polynomial splits or decomposes into linear factors.” https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splitting_field

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: Thank you both for clarifying. Turns out the book I first encountered this material from (Gallian) isn't great at introducing splitting fields, but your points and consulting Hungerford/ Dummit/ et al. has helped me understand. Thank you.